# C++ reading strings from a file gives "-9.25596e+61"

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to read data from a text file (poorly), and it's giving me very weird output. I've done a lot of research and I can't see anything too obvious that I'm doing wrong here.

This is the file I'm trying to read from:

```
Duck, Daffy
77.3
Pluto
88.0
Duck, Donald
94.3
Mouse, Mickey
80.0
Mouse, Minnie
94.3
```

This is my function:

```
int inputData(string names[], double averages[], int size)
{
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("StudentData.txt");

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {

        if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)
        {
            string name;
            inputFile >> name;
            cout << name;

            if (name.find(','))
            {
                inputFile >> name;
                cout << name;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            inputFile.ignore();
            inputFile >> averages[i];
            cout << endl <<  averages[i] << endl;
        }


        count++;

    }

    inputFile.close();

    return count / 2;
}
```

And here is the really strange output when I try running it:

```
Duck,Daffy
77.3
Pluto88.0
-9.25596e+61

-9.25596e+61

-9.25596e+61

-9.25596e+61
```

Comment: From the output, it's pretty clear that you've read `88.0` as Pluto's first name. Read the documentation for `string::find` and see what it returns. (Hint: it's not a `bool`.)

Comment: @molbdnilo You're incredible. I changed it to `if (name.find(',') != -1)` and it works now. Submit your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `if (i == 0 || i % 2 == 0)` -- The test can be simply written as `if (i % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks.

Comment: The question has already been answered, but I think you might be interested in std::getline : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One error that's not causing a bug is that first `if` should just check for `i` being `0` mod `2` since `0` is `0` mod `2` too.

Your bug is in the second `if` which doesn't use `find` correctly.

So you want something more like:

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        string name;
        inputFile >> name;
        cout << name;

        if (name.find(',') != string::npos)
        {    
            inputFile >> name;
            cout << name;
        }
        // ...
```